# Angular Error Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<HttpResponse<any>, number>' is not assignable to 'OperatorFunction<HttpResponse<Object>, unknown>'

Tags: angular, typescript

In an Angular library we are using this code which doesnt compile after upgrading the typescript version to greater than 4.

```
  login(_username: string, _password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._http.post(
      this.directLoginLocation(),
      {username: _username, password: _password},
      {observe: "response"}
    ).pipe(map((resp: HttpResponse<any>) => {
      if (resp.status === 201) {
        return true;
      } else {
        throw new Error("Authentication failed. " + resp.status + ": " + resp.statusText);
      }
    }),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

handelError function is defined as:

```
private handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : AuthenticationService.GENERIC_ERR_MSG;
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

I get the following error:

- error TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<HttpResponse, number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<HttpResponse, unknown>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
  Property '_deprecatedSyncErrorSubscribe' is missing in type 'Observable<HttpResponse>' but required in type 'Observable<HttpResponse>'.

Any ideas on what needs to be tweaked to make it work? May be the return type has to be explicit?

Comment: Never annotate inline callback parameters so change `map((resp: HttpResponse<any>) =>` to `map(resp =>`. Also, why would you use `Observable.throw` in one place and a `throw` statement in another?

Comment: Unfortunately this was done by a developer who is no longer with us as part of a homegrown library he built. Not sure what prompted him to do it. I am trying to understand the motives as well as make it compilable.

Comment: I'm just advising you to be consistent

Comment: thats a good advise to take. I would appreciate if someone could point me to some code which would have better chance of compiling so I can learn from example.

Comment: There is no typescript version 6

Comment: Changed RxJS version to 6 from 7 to fix it.